# Facebook Server-side Conversion Tracking

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I am wondering if it is possible to track conversions based on the information Facebook provides. (FBID, @facebook.com email)

The only option I see is this

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api

And I am still not sure if it would work. If I hashed the @facebook.com email that facebook provides us, would they still be able to associate that with the actual user that clicked the ad?

I am asking this question in relation to facebook message bots. At the moment the only built-in conversion tracking I see is a mutual conversation. I don't see of a way to actually track additional conversions throughout that conversation (for example a successful lead).

Little assistance please :).

Comment: Do you mean conversions or conversations?

Comment: Conversions.

I see that facebook has many options for more complex situations like (offline conversions). I don't see how it's not possible to track sales (or any type of custom event) within a conversation on the facebook messenger platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook recently added documentation for this

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/analytics/quickstart#logging-custom-events

```
var request = require('request');

request.post({ 
  url : "https://graph.facebook.com/your-app-id/activities",
  form: {
    event: 'CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS',
    custom_events: JSON.stringify([{
      _eventName: "fb_mobile_purchase",
      _valueToSum: 55.22,
      fb_currency: 'USD'
    }]),
    advertiser_tracking_enabled: 1,
    application_tracking_enabled: 1,
    extinfo: JSON.stringify(['mb1']),
    page_id: your-page-id,
    page_scoped_user_id: recipientId
  }
}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ 
  console.error(err);
  console.log(httpResponse.statusCode);
  console.log(body);
});
```

This would allow you to track a custom event, and then use that custom event ad a conversion.

Comment: For anyone reading this is no longer available so far as I can make out.